# Creating a topology on a metrizable space.

Tags: general-topology

If I have a topological space $(E,\tau)$ that is metrizable for a metric $d$, and then I look at the set of all open balls in this metric $d$, will this always form a topology? If yes, will this topology be the same $\tau$ ?

Comment: Joseph's answer differ (edit not anymore)

Comment: In general, the collection of open balls will *not* be a topology. Let's think to the case of the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ (which is induced by the metric $(x,y)\mapsto\vert x-y\vert$) ...
However, the unit balls form a base for the topology induced by a metric (by definition !), which means that every open set is the union of a family of open balls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes, the topology induced by the open balls for the metric $d$ will be a topology.

*I want to specify that the topology induced by the open balls is not the set of open balls, but the set of union of open balls.*

- But no, there is no reason that this topology would be the same as $\tau$.

Take for instance $E=\mathbb R$, $d=\vert .\vert$ and $\tau=\mathfrak P(\mathbb R)$ the discrete topology where every subset is open.

You have have two different topologies.

*The answer for your second question is yes if you consider that **metrizable** means that the metric need to be deduced from the topology.*